@beforeSave() is not firing in adonisjs 5
In the following code, as you can see I am trying to update inspection_due_date when updated_at created or updated. But in the database, inspection_due_date is not getting updated. how can I sort this problem? thanks in advance!
  @column.dateTime()
  public inspection_due_date: DateTime

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true, autoUpdate: true })
  public updated_at: DateTime

  @beforeSave()
  public static async setInspectionDueDate(inspection: Inspection) {
    if (inspection.$dirty.updated_at) {
      inspection.inspection_due_date = await inspection.updated_at.plus({ months: 3 })
    }
  }

I checked documentation and other things but it seems I did everything right.

I found a solution to this problem. To help someone in the future, I am answering this question.
Basically, $dirty is triggered when a field is updated or created. since updated_at in my code was set to { autoCreate: true, autoUpdate: true }, $dirty.updated_at was not triggering.
So, what I did is, I manually set updated_at and thus $dirty.updated_at is getting triggered. Following is the updated code.
@column.dateTime()
public inspection_due_date: DateTime

@beforeSave()
  public static async setInspectionDueDate(inspection: Inspection) {
  
  // Manually set updated_at to current DateTime
  inspection.updated_at = DateTime.now()

  if (inspection.$dirty.updated_at) {
    // Now you can safely use the updated_at field
    inspection.inspection_due_date = inspection.updated_at.plus({ months: 3 })
   }
  }

